# form posting on return value of javascript confirm box

Tags: javascript, forms

i have form with few fields and what i want the when someone clicks on submit button then his his submition of form must be confirmed by javascript confirm box and when he clicks on **OK** then the form should be submitted other wise not.
my form structure is

```
    <form method="post" style="margin: 10px;" id="rForm">
    <table style="margin-left:20px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">First Name</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_first_name" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_first_name']) ? $_POST['user_first_name'] : ''); ?>" /> *</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Middle Name</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_middle_name" class="inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_middle_name']) ? $_POST['user_middle_name'] : ''); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Last Name</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_last_name" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_last_name']) ? $_POST['user_last_name'] : ''); ?>" /> *</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Email ID</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_email']) ? $_POST['user_email'] : ''); ?>" /> * </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">City</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_city" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_city']) ? $_POST['user_city'] : ''); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">State</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_state" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_state']) ? $_POST['user_state'] : ''); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Country</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_country" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_country']) ? $_POST['user_country'] : ''); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Postal Code</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_postal_code" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_postal_code']) ? $_POST['user_postal_code'] : ''); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Username</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="text" name="user_id" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['user_id']) ? $_POST['user_id'] : ''); ?>" /> * <span>[<a href="#" title="Username Must be 4 Characters Long">?</a>]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Password</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="password" name="user_key" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" /> * </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">Confirm-Password</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm"><input type="password" name="user_key1" class="validate[required] text-input inputbox box_100" style="width: 190px;" /> * </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="f_title_sm label">User Type</td>
    <td class="f_value_sm">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="user_type" value="<?php echo USER_ROLES::USER_BUYER; ?>" checked="checked" id="buyer" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;<lable style="font-size:12px;" for="buyer">Buyer</lable>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" name="user_type" value="<?php echo USER_ROLES::USER_SELLER; ?>" id="seller"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<lable style="font-size:12px;" for="seller">Seller</lable>&nbsp;&nbsp; 

    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="f_value_sm value"><input type="submit" name="user_reg" class="go backcolr" value="Register" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

so kindly suggest me appropriate solution

Comment: What javascript have you tried?

Comment: Please create a small test case, not just your whole form...

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the form submission using jQuery and show the dialog to confim it or cancel.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
   if(!confirm('Continue?'))
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

`e.preventDefault()`will prevent the submission of the form.

Comment: Maybe this new problem is not related to the question. It could be a new thread probably..

Comment: Thanks for solution and its working fine but a new problem is that the confirmation box is coming twice means if you click submit then you get a confirmation box and if you click cancel and make some changes and then submit then the confirmation box is coming twice actually the number of times you are making changes then same number of times the popbox appers.so any solution for this ?please

Answer (score 0):

try this : `onsubmit="return validation();"`

```
<form method="post" style="margin: 10px;" id="rForm" onsubmit="return validation();">
```

script here :

```
function validation(){
   var conf = confirm("are your sure!");
   if(conf==false){
       return false;
   }
}
```

hope it will help

Comment: As I said above, you don't need a variable and an `if` statement when `return confirm("...");` does the job. But if you do use a variable please declare it with `var` so that it isn't global...

Comment: Thanks for solution and its working fine but a new problem is that the confirmation box is coming twice means if you click submit then you get a confirmation box and if you click cancel and make some changes and then submit then the confirmation box is coming twice actually the number of times you are making changes then same number of times the popbox appers.so any solution for this ?please

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = document.getElementById('rForm');
if (document.addEventListener) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', confirmForm, false);
} else {
    form.attachEvent('onsubmit', confirmForm);
}

function confirmForm(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure ?');
    if (!answer) {
       if(e.preventDefault) {
           e.preventDefault();
       } else {
           e.returnValue = false
       }
    }       
}
```

Comment: it is not working, no confirmation box is being populated and form is submitted

Answer (score -1):

```
        $("form").submit(function() {
            var res = confirm("Are you shure go");
            if(!res){
                return false;

            }
               return true
        });
```

Comment: Won't this give a `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`? (Aside from that, do you really need four lines of code in the function when `return confirm("Message here")` will do it?)

Comment: Form Posting is not pressing submit button, can also be done using the `Enter` key. Use `submit()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for solution and its working fine but a new problem is that the confirmation box is coming twice means if you click submit then you get a confirmation box and if you click cancel and make some changes and then submit then the confirmation box is coming twice actually the number of times you are making changes then same number of times the popbox appers.so any solution for this ?please